# Lightning Access Check Failed! Attribute not visible to markup - Summer '16

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

I'm getting this error when I put my attribute on the page but I can get/set it in my helper without issue. Here's the error:

> [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Access Check Failed! AttributeSet.get(): attribute 'numAF' of component 'markup://c:AffiliationsList {1:1135;a}' is not visible to 'markup://c:AffiliationsList {1:1135;a}'....

Here's my component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,force:hasRecordId" access="public" controller="AffiliationController">
  <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
  <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
  <aura:attribute name="afList" type="AffiliationWrapper[]"/>
  <aura:attribute name="numAf" type="Integer" default="0"/>
  {!v.numAF} ....
```

here's my helper:

```
loadAffiliations : function(cmp, ev) {
    console.log('currentId', cmp.get("v.recordId"));
    var action = cmp.get("c.getAffiliations");
    action.setParams({
        "currentId": cmp.get("v.recordId")
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS") {
            var affiliations = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('numAf before', cmp.get("v.numAf"));

            cmp.set('v.numAf', affiliations.length);
            cmp.set('v.afList', affiliations);
            console.log('numAf after', cmp.get("v.numAf"));
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") {
            console.log('errors', response.getError());
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

The console shows the attribute is being set correctly, so I'm at a loss as to why this is happening. The afList attribute is being set and shows on the page as it should. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `Apex`, `Javascript` code is case-sensitive. I got the error because I used `numAF` instead of `numAf`.

Comment: I got the same error because of a wrong type. The attribute type was supposed to be `Object[]` but it was wrongly set to `Object`.